# juju openstack juju-bootstrap not working properly

Tags: ssh, juju, openstack, cloud

I have configured juju with local and openstack. I followed the instructions here: [Bootstrapping JuJu on top of an OpenStack private cloud](http://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2014/04/29/bootstraping-juju-on-top-of-an-openstack-private-cloud/) for configuring juju on a private openstack deployment.

Juju spawns a new VM in openstack and it is visible in the horizon dashboard but the problem occurs when juju tries to ssh into the newly spawned VM for installing juju agent. This is what I get in the terminal:

```
Bootstrapping environment "openstack"
Starting new instance for initial state server
Launching instance
 - 66a39b56-5e47-495d-a3ba-5278f492cf14
Building tools to upload (1.25.0.1-trusty-amd64)
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 192.168.5.3:22
ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: ssh: connect to host 192.168.5.3 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have been stuck for quite a while now and unable to resolve the issue. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Possibly related: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2299093

Comment: hi,
Same issue here. It seems that juju is trying to connect on ssh with user/password but I configured my openstack to only allow using key-pair. I've configured a ssh key pair for my juju user on openstack but it's not using it when creating the juju controller instance in openstack... so it's stuck.

If you managed to work around this, more information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some (good news): ssh connection solved by 1) forcing the controller on a private network and 2) forcing it to have a public floating ip. The options used (not easy to find these) :   

--config network=<ID_internal_net> --config use-floating-ip=true